# Android Facebook Integration Hash & Release key Error

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

When I run from directly eclipse it successfully work but when I export sign in application package and install exported app then it will give following errors:

invalid key hash.the hash key uR+29vKBjrnn3baLc4CBwhtmJdk does not match any stored key hash.configure your app key hashes at http://developers.facebook.com/APPID

When I put this uR+29vKBjrnn3baLc4CBwhtmJdk in release key then give error like....configure your app key hashes at http://developers.facebook.com/APPID

So what is issues here and hash key n release key different in every time?

Comment: you need to create release hash key

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new Key for your application and it will be created using the Sha1 key of your signed application.The new sha1 key is generated whenever you create a new signed application.Use that sha key

During the process of signing, output similar to that outlined below will appear within the Console panel:

```
[2013-06-13 10:34:39 - ReleaseTest] New keystore C:\Users\nadags\Documents\AndroidReleaseAPK\ReleaseTest.apk has been created.
[2013-06-13 10:34:39 - ReleaseTest] Certificate fingerprints:
[2013-06-13 10:34:39 - ReleaseTest]   MD5 : FA:65:D--------------
[2013-06-13 10:34:39 - ReleaseTest]   SHA1: D1:E-------------------
```

or it will also appear on the popup where you will name your build finally before signing it.
[image]

Use this SHA1 to create new key at facebook developer console and include that in your app.

After you have followed the above procedure, do not right click and run the project again from eclipse, that will make the app to load from its default sha1 key. After you sign the app, manually copy paste the signed .apk to your device. That will make it work.

Note:-
For signing your app in android studio and obtaining new key,you can use [THIS](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) and [THIS](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Generating_a_Signed_Release_APK_File_in_Android_Studio) .

Comment: thanks for response...i already try but not solve my issue...once again thanks

Comment: @AshishTikarye you must be doing something wrong somewhere.Have you enabled the live option for your app

Comment: If not then,
go to your facebook developer console and select your project(app) from app section.Then in status and review turn on the option--Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?. You will need an email id to turn it on so add one if you haven't already.

Comment: thank you Anirudh....now its working after turn on status and review and i got email and name of user but now i want to get mobile number so is it possible to get logged user mobile number....please post your precious answer...i'll wait...and thanks a lot Anirudh.

Comment: @AshishTikarye i dont't think as facebook has limited the data which we can fetch.Check this here:-http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2011/jan/18/facebook-privacy-data